Cant obtain isGroup attribute of the chat in wwebjs
When I call client.getChats() in my wwebjs app I obtain the result like this
PrivateChat {
  id: {
    server: 'g.us',
    user: '120363245...',
    _serialized: '1203632...@g.us'
  },
  name: 'Blu...',
  isGroup: undefined, // that's the fatal line
  isReadOnly: false,
  unreadCount: 0,
  timestamp: 1733520173,
  archived: false,

As you can see isGroup is undefined and the attributes, such as participants, of this chat which is group chat are not available.
Does anyone have any resolution to this issue?
Thx)
I extracted chats and the group chats are not populated with the data about its participants.

"of this chat which is group chat" - if this was actually a group chat, then you should have gotten a GroupChat instance, but you have a PrivateChat instance.

Well, this is a group chat - a chat with multiple participants. The issue is that all chats I retrieve are, for some reason, labeled as PrivateChat and attribute isGroup attribute is always undefined which makes impossible the completion of main task - retrieving the contacts grouped by the chat they pertain to (either personal or group one). Therefore, the question is double: how, do i retrieve all participants of the private chat OR how do i make the chats of my client defined as Chat and GroupChat so the retrieval of contacts there is clear

Just update the whatsapp-web.js library to this version: 1.26.1-alpha.3
npm install whatsapp-web.js@1.26.1-alpha.3
